# jQuery display html in textarea exclude an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 divs in a container. I want to display the html of the container which contains the divs in the textarea. I'm able to do this. The issue is, i don't want to get all the html of the container. I don't want to get #iv #three. I want to copy all the html of the container except div #three. I could use `$('#three').remove()` but i don't want to remove the div,  I just don't want to copy it's html value to textarea. Check jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">test 1 </div>
  <div id="two">test 2 </div>
  <div id="three">test 3 </div>
  <div id="four">test 4 </div>
</div>    
<textarea id="save"></textarea>

var x = $('#container').html();
$('#save').val(x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#container").clone().find("#three").remove().end().html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/21/

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
var x = $('#container').html();
$('#save').val(x);
*/

var lol = $('#container').clone()
$(lol).find('#three').remove();


$('#save').val(lol.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').clone().find('#three').remove().end().html();
```

Technically this is illegal since you are duplicating IDs, but it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/33/

Edit: Someone beat me to it :( Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "";

$('#container div').each( function() {

   if ( this.id != "three" ) {

      text += $(this).html();

   }

});

$('#save').val( text );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/31/

Basically you check the divs inside #container one by one, and check their id. If it's one you want, add their html to a string. Then at the end give that string as your textarea value.